# PHP Timezone display using format method

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

please tell me how can i print data and time in this format using php
2014-03-011T20:34:01Z

i tried this code

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and get something like that
2014-03-11 20:13:20
close enough but not exactly 2014-03-011T20:34:01Z

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format an UTC date to use the Z (Zulu) zone designator in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390784/how-to-format-an-utc-date-to-use-the-z-zulu-zone-designator-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `c` format to get close:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->format('c');
// 2014-03-11T07:55:34+00:00
```

Or just add the `T` and `Z` yourself. Make sure you escape them as they are valid formatting parameters:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
// 2014-03-11T07:56:07Z
```

Comment: In addition to this nice answer op could also have a look at the supported formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this

```
$date = Date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```